# How to merge two repositories

Tags: git, github

I want to establish some rock solid rules we can use to gradually combine our multiple repos into a single repo. I've done this before but only in a simple case.

My starting point is [this article](https://saintgimp.org/2013/01/22/merging-two-git-repositories-into-one-repository-without-losing-file-history/).

In our case we have (evolved) six or so repos and a few months ago I merged one of these into a new one, eventually we want everything to be in this new one without losing history.

Let me emphasize we're talking an organization account in Github and all repos are private and are all forks of these repos.

The challenge I'm seeing - in the general case - is that others have forked these repos and may also have branches on their forks that do not exist in the base repo.

So if I simply merge one base repo into another, the forks of the original repo become invalid and their contents (commits that exist only on the forks) become unusable.

Also - not discussed in that article - is the issue of multiple branches, if the source repo (to be merged from) has umpteen branches, these branches must when all is said and done, be retained or be present in the merged repo.

So how to proceed in this general case? Incidentally we use Smartgit for most of our git work.

Comment: Unless merging here means rewriting the pertinent history, then why would the forks become unusable? The commits inside are just as valid to merge into your final repository as they are in whatever they were originally forked from.

Comment: Not a fan of the process outlined in that article.  It ends with directories doing the work of branches.  The only time that makes sense is if the repos you're merging are separate projects - in which case, keep them in separate repos.

Answer (score 1):

I think some of your concerns are based on a misunderstanding of how git organizes its information.  Still, I would agree that a solid, repeatable plan going in would be a very good idea.

First things first:  You can collect all the objects in every repo, with overlap automatically combined, and all refs present, by simply doing nothing more than a fetch operation against the right remotes.

```
git init
git remote add origin
git remote add dept_A_fork
git remote add dept_B_fork
git fetch --all
```

Now you have a local repo with every branch from every remote.  You have `origin/master`, `dept_A_fork/master`, `dept_B_fork/master`.  If only `dept_B_fork` had a `feature_XYZ` branch, you have `dept_B_fork/feature_XYZ`.

The full history is present for every one of these branches.  If they have shared history, they're already sharing all the objects that are common (including commits).  If someone forked `dept_B_fork`, they can repoint to this new repo as a remote and they'll find everything they need to provide the upstream history to which their local branches are rooted as well.

From there what you need are conventions.  What do you want to do with cases where all repos have a branch?  Merge them all together and make that the "local" ref?  Sure, you can.  Might involve a lot of conflict resolution and testing.

What about a branch that occurs only in some repos?  You *could* just leave the remote refs, but assuming this will be the One True Remote when you're done I'd figure out a way to remap everything to local branches instead.  So maybe the remote ref `refs/remote/dept_B_fork/custom_branch` becomes a local ref `refs/heads/dept_B_fork/custom_branch` (with a little namespacing in there).

The cardinal rule, since you're worried about forks of your forks and keeping them valid, is *don't rebase **anything**.*  Don't cherry pick.  Don't use `filter-branch`.  Don't do squash merges.  Don't do anything that would move any ref in such a way that it no longer reaches a commit it used to reach.

(Some of those rules are arguably overkill if you *really* know what you're doing, but follow them all and you should have no problem.)

This doesn't mean nobody's ever going to have a headache.  They'll have to figure out how to map their tracking info to your new uber-remote because the mapping rules between `dept-B-fork` and `fork-of-dept-B-fork` won't be quite right any more.  But that's not so bad; at least the history is all there and you've left the branch in place (albeit maybe with a new name).  (The only way around remapping of tracking info, btw, is if you know that always, from every fork, the branches with the same name can be merged together to create a branch of that name in the new repo, regardless of what combination of your forks had that branch.)

(You can tell if you did indeed avoid all the headaches; if so you'll be able to cleanly push any branch to the corresponding branch (if one exists) in any remote, with no `--force`/`-f` options.)

Anyway, once everything is reflected in a local branch you could

```
cd ..
git clone --mirror repo-I-just-made new-origin
```

to create a proper origin repo

Comment: I should note that based on your description I'm assuming all the repos share *some* common history - that one is a fork of another, etc.  If this is not true, then fetching all objects into one repo will create a multi-rooted repo.  That's not necessarily bad, but will require special handling if/when you try to merge across those histories.